# Lists in Table Cells Overlap one another

Tags: html, css

[Code here (too long to post in here)](http://jsbin.com/rulibi/4/edit)

For easy organization of elements I would like to display side by side, I use table rows, like:

```
<--!I know this isn't very professional but I don't care-->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><p>Here's a thing</p></td>
        <td><p>Here's another thing</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p>More thing</p></td>
        <td><p>still more thing</p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

this displays as:

```
Here's a thing | Here's another thing

More thing     | Still more thing
```

However, this gives me odd errors with list items overlapping one another (which you can see at JSBin) when there are lists and their items in a table cell. Is there a way to fix it?

Edit: There are a few other problems (random bullet, item with no bullet (might be the random bullet), single list with different bullet style than all the others, etc.) but this one was bugging me the most

Comment: Your cells aren't overlapping. You are using unordered lists, and the dots are appearing outside of the cells, to the left. This is causing it to appear as overlap. To avoid this, either remove the dots (`list-style:none`), or set `overflow:hidden`, or give more padding for the `td`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As AndyM said, you can avoid this by removing the dots, or if you still want to maintain the look of a list, you can apply the list-style-property to it:

```
list-style-property: inside;
```

That should align them correctly, while still looking like lists.